# Selecting a distinct Variable from one column

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the sample of my table:

```
Order_id    Item_id Payment_type
2345        120     Cash  
2345        121     Cash    
3346        122     Cash    
3346        123     Check    
3346        124     Check    
4456        125     Check
4456        126     Check    
5456        127     Cash
```

One order could have one or more items and one or more payment type.
But in my result I want the order id that has only Cash as payment type.
so in the above table, my result should have only 2345 and 5456.

I tried

```
Select order_id
from orders
where (payment_type = 'Cash' and payment_type <> 'Check')
```

but the result was 2345, 3346 and 5456.

I do not want 3346 in my result as it has cash and check payment type.

Comment: You seem to have forgot to add your attempt at a `select` statement. Please edit the question

Comment: Where is `other payment type` in the table. Where are the quotes around `cash` etc

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MINUS set operator (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341)).
Test table:

```
create table T as
select 2345 Order_id, 120 Item_id, 'Cash' Payment_type from dual union all
select 2345, 121, 'Cash' from dual union all
select 3346, 122, 'Cash'  from dual union all
select 3346, 123, 'Check' from dual union all
select 3346, 124, 'Check' from dual union all
select 4456, 125, 'Check' from dual union all
select 4456, 126, 'Check' from dual union all
select 5456, 127, 'Cash'  from dual;
```

Query

```
select order_id
from T
minus
select order_id
from T
where payment_type = 'Check'
;

--result
ORDER_ID  
2345      
5456
```

Dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=119e3065b549d902a5737b40052327c2).

Comment: With `MINUS` you need no `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Option which uses `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 2345 order_id, 120 item_id, 'Cash' payment_type from dual union all
  3   select 2345, 121, 'Cash'  from dual union all
  4   select 3346, 122, 'Cash'  from dual union all
  5   select 3346, 123, 'Check' from dual union all
  6   select 3346, 124, 'Check' from dual union all
  7   select 4456, 125, 'Check' from dual union all
  8   select 4456, 126, 'Check' from dual union all
  9   select 5456, 127, 'Cash'  from dual
 10  )
 11  select order_id
 12  from test
 13  group by order_id
 14  having min(payment_type) = max(payment_type)
 15    and min(payment_type) = 'Cash';

  ORDER_ID
----------
      5456
      2345

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` is applied on each single record. So with `WHERE` you cannot find out whether one record matches 'Cash' and none matches 'Check'. You'd have to aggregate per order ID and use `HAVING` for this:

```
select order_id
from orders
group by order_id
having count(case when payment_type = 'Cash' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when payment_type = 'Check' then 1 end) = 0
order by order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Then the total items would equal the total Cash items.
By summing a CASE you can count the later.

```
select order_id
from orders
group by order_id
having count(*) = sum(case payment_type when 'Cash' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Or by summing a DECODE

```
select order_id
from orders
group by order_id
having count(*) = sum(decode(payment_type,'Cash',1,0))
```